# jquery: Find a string between two strings and wrap it with a span

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have to do something strange (don't ask me why): I have a string an like to replace a part of it by jquery:

**This is the [red]Headline[/red] today** has to be changed to:

```
This is the <span class="red">Headline</span> today
```

The pseudo-tag [red] and [/red] is wrapping the word/phrase that has to be wrapped by the span. It seems to be easy but I'm too stupid today...

Comment: Can you publish the JavaScript Code?

Comment: Where do you have this string? In a variable? In the DOM? Is the `[red]` part fixed, or is there `[blue]` and `[chartreuse]` as well? What rule is there to say that `[red]` should be changed but (say) `[sic]` should not?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `Regex` pattern `/\[(\w+)\](\w+)\[\/(\w+)\]/g`

**Explanation regex pattern**

1. `\[(\w+)\]` its match the first `[red]`
2. `[\/(\w+)\]` match last red like `[\red]`
3. `(\w+)\` the between two `[red](match)[\red]`

[**For more explanation refer**](https://regex101.com/r/4PILKM/1)

```js
var text = 'This is the [red]Headline[/red] today';
console.log(text.replace(/\[(\w+)\](\w+)\[\/(\w+)\]/g, '<span class="$1">$2</span>'))
```

Comment: I got it like that: `$('H1, H2, H3, H4').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\[(\w+)\](\w+)\[\/(\w+)\]/g, '<span class="$1">$2</span>');
    $(this).html(text);
});` but maybe I have to clear $2 because in case of more than one [red] $2 contains and replaces always the first string that was replaced on the page